# Issues with Rust Mutex locks

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a function that given a directory path, would read all its subdirs and return a vector containing the paths of all its subdirs and files. My implementation is done by using a queue. Originally I made it single-threaded, but it takes around 60 seconds to finish. So I tried dividing work in 4 threads. However Mutex locks seem to be blocking my application, and I haven't figured out what the solution could be.

```
fn get_path_files(path: &str) -> Result<Vec<String>, String> {
    let files = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new()));
    let dir_queue = Arc::new(Mutex::new(VecDeque::from([path.to_string()])));

    let mut handles = vec![];

    for _ in 0..4 {
        let files = Arc::clone(&files);
        let dir_queue = Arc::clone(&dir_queue);

        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            while let Some(dir) = dir_queue.lock().unwrap().pop_front() {
                if let Ok(entries) = fs::read_dir(&dir) {
                    for entry in entries {
                        if let Ok(entry) = entry {
                            println!("Dir: {:?}", entry);
                            if entry.file_type().unwrap().is_dir() {
                                dir_queue
                                    .lock()
                                    .unwrap()
                                    .push_back(entry.path().to_string_lossy().to_string());

                                print!("Dir: {:?}", entry.path().to_string_lossy().to_string());
                                files
                                    .lock()
                                    .unwrap()
                                    .push(entry.path().to_string_lossy().to_string());
                            } else {
                                files
                                    .lock()
                                    .unwrap()
                                    .push(entry.path().to_string_lossy().to_string());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    let result = files.lock().unwrap().clone();

    Ok(result)
}
```

EDIT:

Changing

```
while let Some(dir) = dir_queue.lock().unwrap().pop_front() {
```

To

```
while dir_queue.lock().unwrap().len() > 0 {
    let dir = dir_queue.lock().unwrap().pop_front().unwrap();
```

Seems to do the job. However, when the first thread pops from the queue, the other 3 check it's empty and stop working, so I'm spawning 4 threads but just 1 is working. I wonder if there's a way to check if any thread is working and continue in that case.
Something like:

```
while dir_queue.lock().unwrap().len() > 0 || any_thread_working{
    let dir = dir_queue.lock().unwrap().pop_front().unwrap();
```

Comment: If you're doing this for production usage, I recommend the [`walkdir`](https://docs.rs/walkdir/latest/walkdir/) crate.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman is not really for production. I'm learning rust and this project is a file explorer, as fast as it can be. I heard of walkdir, but I want to implement my own algorithm for better learning.

Comment: Adding to Chayim's suggestion, an mpmc queue (e.g. from crossbeam) would also be a good idea instead of doing that by hand with a big lock.

Comment: @Masklinn I didn't know about mpmc queues, will check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test it right now, but I believe the issue is some sort of lifetime extension of the MutexGuard:

```
while let Some(dir) = dir_queue.lock().unwrap().pop_front() {
```

`dir_queue.lock()` creates a temporary, that temporary is kept alive until the end of the statement, which is *until the end of the iteration*. Similar to https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/78390

I think replacing the start of the loop with:

```
loop {
    let v = dir_queue.lock().unwrap().pop_front();
    let Some(dir) = v else { break; };
```

should fix the issue, but again, can't test it.

Comment: That fixes the issue with the lock, thanks. I still have an issue with 3 threads stopping because there are no more dirs in the queue, when the first one is running.

Comment: @ElAlien725 This is a new issue, you should ask a new question.

Comment: I have the impression that this is not related to lifetime extension. It's just how temporaries work, isn't it? https://rustwiki.org/en/reference/destructors.html#temporary-lifetime-extension